# how to make parallel connection to teradata using Spark sql

Tags: pyspark, teradata, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert Spark DataFrame to Teradata table using spark sql jdbc connection.

**Code:**

```
properties = {
    "TMODE","TERA",
    "TYPE","FASTLOAD"
}
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:teradata://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}?user=${jdbcUsername}&password=${jdbcPassword}"
df.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="someTable", mode='append', properties=properties)
```

But when i execute the job, its running only one executor and one connection to teradata.

How to make parallel connection to Teradata, what is the property needs to be included to make multiple parallel connections to Teradata?

**update:**

I was going through this databricks blog, it says, based on the number of partitions in DataFrame, it will create multiple connections.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Comment: You might also check if your company uses Teradata's QueryGrid, there's a Spark connector.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? Im facing it now

Comment: @semicolon check my update on the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like this, basically it creates number of parallel connections based on `numPartitions` and then you can define lowerBound and upperBound value for each partition ( how many records it has to read )

```
val df = (spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl,
  table="employees",
  columnName="emp_no",
  lowerBound=1L,
  upperBound=100000L,
  numPartitions=100,
  connectionProperties=connectionProperties))
display(df)
```